# The global variable doesn't keep its value

Tags: asp.net, postback

The problem is , every time i do a postback my variable "value" doesn't keep it's previous value, and always the dictionary is empty. It doesn't have any previous saved data. How can i make it to save data ?

this is the code :

```
public partial class MyCart : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            public Dictionary<string, string> value = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();                
                    textbox.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
                    textbox.ID = "textbox" + p.IDProduct.ToString();
                    Button button = new Button();
            }

            void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                   value.Add(((TextBox)sender).ID, ((TextBox)sender).Text);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `global` variable are recreated on *Postback* you probably need to put the variable in `ViewState` for keep its data between postbacks.

If data is small the its fine with `ViewState` but if data is large then your might need to think an alternative medium of storage could be database.

To do it with ViewState you would need something like.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> value = new Dictionary<string, string>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     if(ViewState["valDic"] != null)
         value = (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewState["valDic"];
     TextBox textbox = new TextBox();                
     textbox.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
     textbox.ID = "textbox" + p.IDProduct.ToString();
     Button button = new Button();
}   

void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     value.Add(((TextBox)sender).ID, ((TextBox)sender).Text);
     ViewState["valDic"] = value;
}
```

> View state is the method that the ASP.NET page framework uses to
>   preserve page and control values between round trips. When the HTML
>   markup for the page is rendered, the current state of the page and
>   values that must be retained during postback are serialized into
>   base64-encoded strings. This information is then put into the view
>   state hidden field or fields, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

After postbacks the variables lose the value as they are recreated..You can depend HTML hidden inputs..

**Markup:**

```
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden"  runat="server"  value=""/>
```

**Code behind:**

```
Hidden1.value="something";
```